# Prove that logarithmic function is big oh of logarithm of constant

Tags: solution-verification, asymptotics

Let $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^{\geq 0}}$. Let $a \in \mathbb{R^{+}}$.

Assume $\exists x_{1}, k_{0} \in \mathbb{R^{+}}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}, n \geq k_{0} \implies f(n) \leq x_{1}n^{a}$.
Prove that $\exists x_{2}, k_{1} \in \mathbb{R^{+}}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}, n \geq k_{0} \implies \log_{2}(f(n) )\leq x_{2}\log_{2}(n)$.

I started with $$f(n) \leq x_{1}n^{a} \\ 
\log_{2}(f(n)) \leq \log_{2}(x_{1}n^{a}) \\
\log_{2}(f(n)) \leq \log_{2}(x_{1}) +a\log_{2}n \\$$
And then to continue with a choice of $x_{2}$, proceeded with following equation by isolating $x_{2}$.
$$x_{2} = \frac{\log_{2}(x_{1}) + a\log_{2}n}{\log_{2}n} \\
x_2 = \log_{n}x_{1}+a $$
Is this choice of $x_{2}$ good enough to prove this statement?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. A small point on terminology: $n\mapsto n$ is the _identity_ function, not a _constant_ function.

Answer (score 1):

Your $x_2$ depends on $n$, but the introduction of $\exists x_2$ comes before the introduction of $\forall n$. This is not allowed. You need to find an $x_2$ independent of $n$.

Comment: Wasn't $n$ introduced earlier than $x_{2}$, because it is in assumption?

Comment: That's a different $n$. They are just variables, we could have renamed the first $n$ to be e.g. $s$ and nothing would change.

Comment: Makes sense , could you suggest an approach how to find it withour violating quantifiers?

Comment: Note that $\log_2 x_1$ is a constant by assumption. You can try to find an upper bound for $\log_{2}(x_{1}) +a\log_{2}n$. This upper bound will also be an upper bound for $\log_2 f(n)$.